# How to match the index of two anchors within two rows using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a container with two rows of links. I need to add a `nav_link--hover` class to both links that link to the same place, which also have the same index number within the parent div.

How can this be updated to match two anchors using the index number instead of just the first one found in the index of the container?

For example, if I hover over the fourth link, I want the `nav_link--hover` class to be applied to the second link (in row one) and the second link (in row two).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/3z2cgb71/)

```
<nav class="nav_container">
  <div class="row-one">
    <a href="#a" class="nav_link">
      <div class="nav_image sprite-cat"><img></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#b" class="nav_link">
      <div class="nav_image sprite-cat2"><img></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row-two">
    <a href="#a" class="nav_link">
      <div class="nav_text">Item One</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#b" class="nav_link">
      <div class="nav_text">Item Two</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>

<script>
var $container = $('.nav_container');

$('.nav_link').each(function(i) {
  $(this).on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $container.find('.nav_link').eq(i).addClass('nav_link--hover');
    },
    mouseout:  function() {
      $container.find('.nav_link').eq(i).removeClass('nav_link--hover');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add your CSS file to the JSFiddle?

Comment: this isn't the exact solution you're asking for but you could look into css selector's by html attr and grab the href of the event's sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the index, you can use `index()` with `nth_child` to target all children of that index etc.

```
var $container = $('.nav_container');

$('.nav_link').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.nav_link:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('nav_link--hover');
    },
    mouseleave:  function() {
      $('.nav_link:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('nav_link--hover');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3z2cgb71/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.nav_link').each(function(i) {
  $(this).on({
    mouseover: function() {
      // get the href link
      var link = $(this).prop('href');
      //get the anchor
      var hash = link.substring(link.indexOf("#")+1);
      // find all the a tags with href = #anchor, and add css class
      $("a[href='#"+hash+"']").addClass('nav_link--hover');
    },
    mouseout:  function() {
      var link = $(this).prop('href');
      var hash = link.substring(link.indexOf("#")+1);
      $("a[href='#"+hash+"']").removeClass('nav_link--hover');
    }
  });
});
```

And the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z2cgb71/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

Updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qxatn2d1/

```
$('.nav_link').each(function(i) {
  $(this).on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $('a[href="'+ $(this).attr('href') +'"]').addClass('nav_link--hover');
    },
    mouseout:  function() {
        $('a[href="'+ $(this).attr('href') +'"]').removeClass('nav_link--hover');
    }
  });
});
```

Did the trick. It is looking for all `a` elements with the same href. I would prefer to change your html but for this specific question I think this is your solution..

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: edit for only in the nav container update to `$('.nav_container > a[href...`.